# xsd : restrict attribute defined in base type

Tags: xsd

Consider the following xsd. For Addr, city can be any string. I want to restrict city attribute in USAddr to follow some regular expression. How can I do this ? Please note the city in the base type 'Addr' should still be able to have any string without any restriction. Thanks !

```
<?xml version="1.0"?><xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">

<xs:complexType name="Addr">
  <xs:attribute name="city" type="xs:string" use="required"/>
</xs:complexType>


<xs:complexType name="USAddr">
  <xs:complexContent>
    <xs:extension base="Addr">
      <xs:attribute name="state" type="xs:string" use="required"/>
    </xs:extension>
  </xs:complexContent>
</xs:complexType>

<xs:element name="addr" type="USAddr"/>

</xs:schema>
```

xml :

```
<addr city='abc' state='aaa'/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Attributes can be any simple type, and simple types can have restrictions.  So first, define a simple type with the desired regular expression:

```
<xs:simpleType name="USCity">
  <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
     <xs:pattern value="[a-zA-Z\.]+ ([a-zA-Z]+)*"/> <!-- For example -->
  </xs:restriction>
</xs:simpleType>
```

Then set the type of the city attribute to "USCity".

Comment: I forgot to mention the base type Addr should accept any string for the city. So I cannot change the city type to USCity in the base type Addr.

Comment: You can redefine types or entities, but AFAIK there is no way to redefine attributes within a type extension, which is what would be required.  In this case I would suggest that USAddr and Addr be two distinct types that happen to have similar (but not identical) structures.